# Win10: Notepad: How to change the default font?

Tags: windows-10, notepad

I am a heavy user of notepad. (notepad.exe, part of the Windows OS)

I sometimes increase to a rather large font, when I am screen sharing an outline.

Generally, this font size setting is lost when I exit notepad, which is fine.

On one of my systems (a quite clean Microsoft Surface 7), the font change stuck (to 36 point bold) and I have to set it to something normal every time I use notepad.

How do I get the notepad font setting put back to its default?

Thanks!

Comment: Please kindly check if methods in this article was helpful to you:[How to Restore Default Windows Notepad Settings](https://petri.com/how-to-restore-default-windows-notepad-settings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed it with a slightly different approach.

I used the steps described [here](https://www.top-password.com/blog/reset-notepad-to-default-settings-in-windows/), but instead of DELETING the whole /Notepad branch, I instead made a more minimal change by renaming three leaf elements under

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Notepad
```

I renamed the following three (which preserves the old value in case I want to go back), by adding a hyphen to the beginning of each name:

```
iPointSize
lfFaceName
lfWeight
```

And all fixed!

The open question, fwiw, is: How / when do these values ever get saved to the registry?  That is unknown to me so far. E.g. how to properly control this from the app, not in regedit (of all places...).

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://www.top-password.com/blog/reset-notepad-to-default-settings-in-windows/):

> 1. Press the Windows key + R to open the Run command box. Type regedit and press Enter.
> 2. When Registry Editor is launched, navigate to the following key:
>    `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad`
> 3. Right-click on the Notepad key in the left pane, and then select Delete from the pop-up menu.
> 4. Click Yes to confirm your operation. All your saved settings in Notepad will be deleted. Your Notepad will be back to the default settings on the next run.